# linux C server client streaming files

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to stream files from the client to the server, but there is a incompatible data type from FILE to char, so everytime i run the client it gives me a segmentation error. I dont know how to get around this. Attached is the code for the server and client and below the problem with the client. i am trying to read file from client to buffer send it to server and server will read file from buffer and write it to a file.
client side  http://pastebin.com/QtLbMgP3

server side  http://pastebin.com/8PNchBUZ

```
// n = write(sock,"send me your message",18);
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
        ptr_myfile=fopen("test2.txt","w");

         for(counter=1;counter <=10;counter++){
             fwrite(&ptr_myfile,sizeof(*buffer),1,buffer);
             n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
             n = write(sockfd,buffer,18);

             n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
             if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
             bzero(buffer,256);
             n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
             if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
             // printf("%s\n",buffer);
         };//close for loop
    close(sockfd);

    }// close event loop
    return 0;
}// close main function
```

Comment: Please learn to indent your code in an orthodox manner.  I fixed the worst of it, but there is still quite a lot of room for improvement.  Also, in the line marked `};//close for loop`, the semi-colon is redundant; it creates an empty statement immediately after the body of the loop.  Don't forget to check that the `fopen()` worked; files notoriously aren't there or don't have the right permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Without going through all your code, the `read`, `write`, `close` series of APIs (NOT `fopen`, `fread`, etc) have an integer descriptor, not a `FILE*`.

You can't mix `FILE*` with `int`.

Comment: how would i be able to write from a file into a buffer i wanted to send it over through to my server

Comment: Well at least the answer correctly points out a fundamental conceptual flaw of FILE * vs descriptor. If any thing this should help write the correct solution. Although it's not a complete answer, but i don't see why this is unhelpful

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this line here:

```
fwrite(&ptr_myfile,sizeof(*buffer),1,buffer);
```

How does that even compile?

This is likely correct:

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), ptr_myfile );
```

The above line will read *up to* 256 bytes (the size of your buffer array) from the file and copy the data into *buffer*.  Notice that I'm passing ptr_myfile, not &ptr_myfile.

Comment: thank you, i have no compile errors, but how do i save it into a file in my server side i though it was supposed to save it

Comment: @user1509326 Even if it does compile for some reason that we can't seem to pick, it is outright wrong to use FILE* where you need to use an integer descriptor. It definitely is not going to work that way. Please learn the difference between a FILE * vs a descriptor and then use appropriately.

Comment: @fayyazkl i changed fwrite to selbie's suggestion that is why it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Check your fwrite statement, are you trying to write into the file, or read from the file into the buffer?

If it is the previous case, then use fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer),1, ptr_myfile)  i.e. the stream to which you are writing to is the last variable.

If the case is latter then you will first need to read from the stream using fgets or getchar or some function like that before you actually put it into the buffer.

Hope it helps!

---

Okay, to read a file at the client and send it to server,

```
fp=fopen("<filename>", "r");
//This opens the file and initializes the pointer fp to the start of the file Start of
//the file, not its text necessarily
```

Now you could use fgetc() function [Character by character] or fgets() function [In case the text is formatted, you can read the entire line into the buffer] to read from your file into the buffer.

```
fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fp);
//This could be ambiguous as the second argument should correspond to
//pre-known limit of bytes to read here some Macro maybe.
```

Now, simple use send() to dispatch this buffer to server.

On the server side, receive the input data from network into some 'buffer' using recv() and use fputs or fprintf or any convenient function to write into the file opened there in Write mode.

Comment: and the server side would be fopen with write permission and fread to extract into the file correct?

Comment: i am trying to read file from client to buffer send it to server and server will read file from buffer and write it to a file.

Comment: I've added some explanation in the comment above, have a look.

Comment: sne as it is or do i have to specify like this? send(sockfd, "$C", 2, 0);

Comment: refer to man pages, yes, you've to send it the way you've written in the comment above. send(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer),<FLAGS>);